# Why did the Federal reserve balance sheet capital drop by 32% in Dec 2015?

Tags: federal-reserve

Here's a graph of the capital on the Federal reserve balance sheet from 2003 until present:

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/WCTCL

[image]

Capital dropped by 32% in December 2015.

Is there anywhere I can read about why the capital dropped so dramatically at that point?

And perhaps why has it not changed much since then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Fixing America's Surface Transportation Act (FAST), which was enacted on December 4, 2015, requires that aggregate Federal Reserve Bank surplus not exceed \$10 billion.

The amounts of the line items "Other liabilities and capital" on table 1, and "Surplus" on tables 5 and 6 reflect the payment of approximately \$19.3 billion to Treasury on December 28, 2015, which was necessary to reduce aggregate Reserve Bank surplus to the \$10 billion limitation in the FAST Act.

[Source: Factors Affecting Reserve Balances - H.4.1](https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h41/20151231/)

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Comment: and that money is held in the *Treasury General Account* with *The Federal Reserve Bank of New York*...